# Shared runtime Excel add in no longer uses IE11 - Bug or feature?

Tags: excel, office-js

My Excel add in with custom functions using a shared runtime was happily chugging along with the IE11 webview, until about a week ago when it stopped working because it started running only on the Edgium  webview.

I think the documentation still says the expected webview is IE11 in the shared runtimes page, but the webviews page could be interpreted as saying it's the edge2 webview.

Did anybody else see the same effect?  I mean, that's great if it works (My add in has other problems now, and I can't fully test), I just didn't expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature. See this note from the article [Browsers used by Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)

> If your add-in includes the `<Runtimes>` element in the manifest, then it will not use Microsoft Edge with the original WebView (EdgeHTML). If the conditions for using Microsoft Edge with WebView2 (Chromium-based) are met, then the add-in uses that browser. Otherwise, it uses Internet Explorer 11 regardless of the Windows or Microsoft 365 version. For more information, see Runtimes.